# timing of buttons using jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

i have to display data according to button clicks .it is done simply using jquery .Now the problem is that i want to automate these buttons ..eg when the page loads then data is displayed according to first button(as if 1st button is clicked) , then after 2 seconds data is displayed according to second button(as if 2nd  button is clicked) , then after 2 more seconds data is displayed according to third button (as if 1st button is clicked) .

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $(".headerClass").text("Top Line Stats !!")
    $(".InformationItem").hide();
     $(".informationContainer div[data-id=1]").show();



 //   window.setInterval(function () { DisplaySuccessiveData() }, 10000)
});

$(".listItem").click(function () {
    var index = $(this).attr("data-id");
    $(".InformationItem").hide();
    $(".informationContainer div[data-id=" + index + "]").fadeIn(1000);
});
```

How to proceed ? i am a beginner and dont know much about coding .
i am not able to properly apply Setinterval and settimeout functions . plz guide me 
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use..

```
window.setInterval(yourfunction, 10000);

function yourfunction() { alert('test'); }
```

which will call you function after time has elapsed

Comment: Thanks Jonathan . but how should the fuction be defined in such case , means i am creating the parent divs dynamically which store data (dere r 4 divs and each contain 3 child divs in which data is displayed )On clicking of 1st button data on 1st parent div is displayed (which has 3 child divs as stated .) I am trying the setinterval() but not getting correct values . Can u plz demonstrate an example in which automation of button is dere ???